# Wordpress - Showing list of most recent posts from all categories, inside a category page

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

New to WordPress in general, been having fun playing about with themes.

I have a site at the moment with a Latest Posts box at the top. I want this to display the 5 latest posts made to any category.

The problem I have is, this list only display posts from the category you are currently on. I.e., when on `website.com/?cat=6`, it only displays posts from category 6, but I want it to always have a list from all categories.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function should do what you want, in addition examples have been provided:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts